# How do I re-create a family mailing list from a contact list created in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, contacts

My wife has been assembling a mailing list in Excel for Christmas cards with columns 
for names & address.  I decided to expand the list to include emails and phone numbers 
but this then 'breaks' her original design as the original 'family'-oriented rows are
now people-oriented ones spread across multiple rows but sharing the same mailing address.

Original list:

```
Smith   Bob & Jane  123 Main St     Stockton CA
Jones   Dave & Sue  456 Adams Rd    Carmel  CA
```

turned into:

```
Smith   Bob     123 Main St     Stockton CA bsmith@hotmail.com  (444) 123-2342
Smith   Jane    123 Main St     Stockton CA jsmith@hotmail.com  (444) 345-4565
Jones   Dave    456 Adams Rd    Carmel  CA  djones@aol.com      (415) 453-3454
Jones   Sue     456 Adams Rd    Carmel  CA  sjones@aol.com      (512) 234-3433
```

What is the best way to keep my wife happy by reconstituting her original mailing list
every November?  I'm presuming a macro that uses addresses as unique key, copies
them to a new sheet and then pulls in the names?  Is this considered a 'view' in Excel
parlance?  An initial skeleton would be most helpful, VB isn't my forte.

Comment: You can do this with Power Query.  Delete the unwanted columns. Group the table by `LastName, StreetAddress, City State`.  Convert the resultant table into a `List` of the First names.  Extract those values with a concatenator of  ` & `.  Rearrange the columns and you're done.  And this can be repeated every year.

Comment: This sounds perfect, I hadn't heard of Power Query before, will investigate.  Thanks!

Comment: Well post back if you run into problems.  But be sure to flag it so I'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to suggest a code-less way first. An easy way would be to add a type column and an index column, and  give your entries a "salutation" record, e.g.:

```
S 1 Bob & Jane Smith   123 Main St     Stockton CA
F 1 Smith   Bob        123 Main St     Stockton CA bsmith@hotmail.com  (444) 123-2342
F 1 Smith   Jane       123 Main St     Stockton CA jsmith@hotmail.com  (444) 345-4565
S 8 The Jones Family   456 Adams Rd    Carmel  CA
F 8 Jones   Dave       456 Adams Rd    Carmel  CA  djones@aol.com      (415) 453-3454
F 8 Jones   Sue        456 Adams Rd    Carmel  CA  sjones@aol.com      (512) 234-3433
S 9 The Other Joneses ...
```

With this layout, you could use filters to sort and select data.

Comment: I like the sentiment but the added maintenance and potential conflicts lead me to a programmatic solution.  Thanks.